# not getting file while routing

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am getting an error while routing file as Error: file not found

File structure

```
Controller
--orgaizationController
--blogesController
--pagesController

Views
--organization.ejs
--bloges.ejs
--pages.ejs
--index.ejs
```

organizationController.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/',async (req,res) => {

    res.render('index');
});



router.get('/addedOrganization', async (req,res) => {
    res.render('addedOrganization' , {});

});
```

server.js

```
const blogsController = require('./Controllers/campaignController');
const organizationController = require('./Controllers/campaignController');
const pagesController = require('./Controllers/campaignController');
app.use('/', organizationController)
app.use('/', blogsController)
app.use('/', pagesController)
```

Image
[image]

But when I change app.use('/', organizationController) to app.use('/organiztion', organizationController) I get the index page i.e my homepage
Please anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this middleware to render views without mentioning the path

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: I have mentioned that path then also file not found